# How to add a count column based on filter condition rather than grouping in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is a subset of my asset data

```
# df1 <- AllAssets %>%
#   filter(country %in% c('Morocco', 'Gabon', 'Tunisia')) %>%
#   group_by(country, named, active) %>%
#   summarize(assets = n())
```

Equivalent to this dataframe here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("Gabon", "Gabon", "Gabon", "Morocco", 
"Morocco", "Tunisia", "Tunisia", "Tunisia"), named = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), active = c(1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), assets = c(8L, 305L, 271L, 254L, 18L, 24L, 
350L, 282L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L), .Names = c("country", 
"named", "active", "assets")) %>% as.tibble() %>% group_by(country, named)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   country, named [5]
# country named active assets
# <chr>   <lgl>  <dbl>  <int>
# 1 Gabon   FALSE     1.      8
# 2 Gabon   TRUE      0.    305
# 3 Gabon   TRUE      1.    271
# 4 Morocco TRUE      0.    254
# 5 Morocco TRUE      1.     18
# 6 Tunisia FALSE     0.     24
# 7 Tunisia TRUE      0.    350
# 8 Tunisia TRUE      1.    282
```

I'm making a spreadsheet that counts a country's # of assets according to different variable conditions. Is there a simpler, cleaner way to get the output I've made than what I've written below?

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(ctry_namedTF_count = sum(assets)) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(ctry_count = sum(assets)) %>% 
  filter(named == TRUE, active == 1) %>% 
  select(-(named:active)) %>% 
  rename(named_active = assets, 
         TotalAssets = ctry_count,
         named = ctry_namedTF_count)

# Output:
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   country [3]
  country named_active named TotalAssets
  <chr>          <int> <int>       <int>
1 Gabon            271   576         584
2 Morocco           18   272         272
3 Tunisia          282   632         656
```

I'm essentially 'rolling-up' my dataframe as described in the [dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) (Ctrl-F 'roll-up') with repeated calls to sum(), and adding a number repeatedly rather than just counting grouping cases. But what I have, while functional, is difficult to read and I'm wondering if there's an easier way or custom function that would make more sense.

For example, dplyr::add_count is extremely simple to use to add a column that counts group cases within one or more columns,

```
> df1 %>% add_count(country, named)
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   country, named [5]
  country named active assets     n
  <chr>   <lgl>  <dbl>  <int> <int>
1 Gabon   FALSE     1.      8     1
2 Gabon   TRUE      0.    305     2
3 Gabon   TRUE      1.    271     2
4 Morocco TRUE      0.    254     2
5 Morocco TRUE      1.     18     2
6 Tunisia FALSE     0.     24     1
7 Tunisia TRUE      0.    350     2
8 Tunisia TRUE      1.    282     2
```

and I'm wondering if there's something that sums a variable across these groupings instead.

Does any function like this exist in base R or other munging packages? 
Something like `df1 %>% add_aggregate_by_vars_filters(vars = named, filter = 'named == TRUE', sum_var = assets)`, or something similarly clean and practical?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I think there's a much easier way to do it if you sum your assets ONLY when you meet certain conditions. I posted an answer below...

Comment: No you're right. I just forget too easily about simple vector operations when I'm in dplyr-land. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(list(country = c("Gabon", "Gabon", "Gabon", "Morocco", 
"Morocco", "Tunisia", "Tunisia", "Tunisia"), named = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), active = c(1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), assets = c(8L, 305L, 271L, 254L, 18L, 24L, 
350L, 282L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L), .Names = c("country", 
"named", "active", "assets"))

df1 %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise(named_active = sum(assets[named==TRUE & active==1]),
            named = sum(assets[named==TRUE]),
            TotalAssets = sum(assets[active==1]))

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   country named_active named TotalAssets
#   <chr>          <int> <int>       <int>
# 1 Gabon            271   576         279
# 2 Morocco           18   272          18
# 3 Tunisia          282   632         282
```